# Ctest get number of tests passed/failed in script

Tags: cmake, ctest

Is there a straightforward way when using ctest to get the number of tests passed (and/or failed) within a script, e.g., BASH, without grep-ping through a generated output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a straightforward way ... without grep-ping

No, I believe there is not.

You can also "grep" the count the lines `Test failed.` and `Test passed.` from CMake `the_build_dir/Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log`.

You could potentially generate ctest XML report to a dashboard and then parse the XML reports (instead of sending them). It's nowhere as straightforward, as ctest script has to be written that configures, builds and tests the project and then separate XML tool needs to parse the result.

You can also run a cdash server and let that ctest script upload the results to cdash and then query cdash server with simple `curl 'https://your.cdash.server/api/v1/index.php?project=TheProjectName' | jq '.buildgroups[] | select(.id == 2).builds[] | { "pass": .test.pass, "fail": .test.fail, }`. The querying is simple, but.. it needs to run a cdash server and also test with ctest script, it's not near straightforward..

Btw, it's easy to get the number of failed tests - it's just `wc -l the_build_dir/Testing/Temporary/LastTestsFailed.log`.